# Create username tag in input-tags using Spatie-Tags in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, tags

I just want to create post then tag input by using input-tags, and I will tag the username or firstame/lastname and if the user has exist in the User model, and was tagged in to that particular post, they can see the post details.

I dont know if the Spatie-tags can do this kind of feature.

```
    public function spatieCreate()
    {
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('spatie-create', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function spatieStore(Request $request)`
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'text' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required',
        ]);

        $post = new Post;
        $post->text = $request->text;
        $post->description = $request->description;
        $post->user_id  = auth()->id();
        $post->save();`

       $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);
        $post->attachTags($tags);
        $post->save();

      
       return back()->with('success','Post added to database.');
    }
```

This is the spatie-tags migration default

[image]

I tried put some foreignID to the crate-tags-table migration, but it says error

Comment: Post would be created by someone else and they will be able to tag other username / firstname / lastname of another user to the post??? and if they are tagged in the post then only will they be able to see the post details???

or the user who created the Post will be tagged in the Post???

// Sorry i am bit confused over what exactly is the requirement here...

Comment: Yes, they will only see the post details from the User that created the post
like for example in facebook or twitter, we use @ to tag or mention other user so that they can see the post.